# Carousel Bootstrap Quebrado

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, owl-carousel

Boa tarde, estou com problema com `carousel` do bootstrap, projeto em angular 7.

Ao adicionar:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

na folha de estilo.O `carousel` slide funciona, passa as imgs, porém ao passar, a barra de rolagem sobe ou desce e embaixo do `carousel` move um fundo junto com a img . Tirando `css` acima da folha de estilo, funciona normalmente. Preciso utilizar c pois projeto ja esta em andamento baseado no mesmo .

Restante do codigo :

```css
body {
  font-family: $fonts;
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
  position: relative;
  color: $font_color;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  a,
  a:visited {
    color: $link_color;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  a:hover {
    color: $link_hover_color;
  }
}
.div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

html
`carousel` padrão do bootstrap

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir o problema. Você consegue criar um _fiddle_ com o problema acontecendo?

Comment: Se ainda continuar com o erro poste o problema no codepen ou jsfiddeli para a gente poder simular o problema, pois só com o que foi apresentado na pergunta esta difícil propor outra solução

Comment: https://codepen.io/gring0/pen/byNgqG pronto obg pela atenção.
apenas com barra de cima com 2 imgs uma a esquerda e uma a direita .
 carousel que esta quebrando.

Comment: Cara não ta quebrando nada olha aqui o Slider normal, rodando no Bootstrap 4, https://jsfiddle.net/taL1pskx/ outra coisa, pq o caminha da sua imagem tem o texto "Slide" no final? Isso me parece errado `src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300?auto=yes&text=Segundo Slide"`

Comment: como já comentado com *,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
 nao roda.
coloca <br> um espaço olha em baixo do carousel e olha na barra de rolagem ira ver que esta quebrado , ela se movimenta ...
vlw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe uma forma de reverter esse CSS apenas para os filhos de um determinado Container. Então, no caso, vc coloca o Carrossel dentro de uma `section` e determina que tudo dentro dessa section vai ter outros valores... valores iniciais...

Como vc tem um seletor universal `*` que vc não quer deixar incidir no Carrossel vc coloca `section * { outras propriedades }` e o Carrossel dentro dessa `section`.

```
section * {
    box-sizing: initial;
    padding: initial;
    margin: initial;
}
```

Veja esse exemplo, eu tenho uma `div` com a classe `.box` e nela o CSS do `*` incidi diretamente, já no mesma `div` dentro de uma section eu reverti as propriedades para os valores iniciais.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima

```css
body {
    display: flex;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 10px solid #000;
}
section * {
    box-sizing: initial;
    padding: initial;
    margin: initial;
}
section {
    border: 1px solid #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<section>
    <div class="box"></div>
    box dentro da section
</section>
```